# Перенаправление домена на другой домен

Tags: hosts, http-redirect

Есть домен ohhioshop.com и есть домен Ohhio.me. Оба на разных серверах,  один для теста второй рабочий. Нужно что бы ohhioshop.com переходил на Ohhio.me. 
Оба домена зарегистрированы на одном сервере.
Подменить ип просто,  не могу перенаправить на Ohhio. me, сервис пишет ошибку.

Comment: А что используется в качестве web-сервера? Если речь, конечно, о сайте

Comment: Веб-сервер Apache.

Comment: Если для вас подошёл один из ответов, отметьте его пожалуйста как правильный

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать разные методы перенаправление:

> HTML

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://new-website.com'" />
```

> JavaScript

```
window.location = "http://new-website.com";
```

Однако JavaScript весьма странен и есть много способов сделать это:

```
window.location = "http://new-website.com";
window.location.href = "http://new-website.com";
window.location.assign("http://new-website.com");
window.location.replace("http://new-website.com");
```

> Apache

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.new-website.com
```

> .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-website.com [L,R=permanent]
```

Либо все сделать редирект на вашем хостинге.

Comment: тогда  dev.ohhioshop.com редиректит на Ohhio.me а это не нужно.

Comment: @ДимаБаловнев тогда я не пойму ваш вопрос. Попробуйте его перефразировать. Допишите всю информацию и тд

Comment: Два сервак, и два домена   ohhioshop.com Ohhio.me. есть еще субдомен,  dev.ohhioshop.com,  как сделать редирект именно одного домена, а именно ohhioshop.com, не затронул,  девовский домен.

Comment: @ДимаБаловнев  Первый вариант с HTML, не затронит дев

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 1):

Если оба домена ведут на один веб-сервер apache просто добавьте алиас для хоста.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  ohhio.me
    ServerAlias ohhioshop.com
    ...
    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

---

NOTE

Судя по всему, речь идёт не о серверах, а о виртуальных хостах, т.к. ip доменов один и тот же.